# Fail installing modbus-tcp with rosdep

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, my question is pretty simple.

I wanted to install the robotiq gripper packages, I have already git-clone them, but trying to catkin_make, it ends with this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "socketcan_interface" with any of the following names:

    socketcan_interfaceConfig.cmake
    socketcan_interface-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "socketcan_interface" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "socketcan_interface_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "socketcan_interface" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

have anyone faced the same error? ¿does anyone knows what should I do?

Thank you all for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255682/fail-installing-modbus-tcp-with-rosdep/) by [meimar12](https://answers.ros.org/users/29487/meimar12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q252478 for instructions on how to build things from sources. Just `git clone`-ing is *not enough*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0